# Probability identity similar to $P(X_J=x, X_K=y)=\sum_{z} P(X_{J \cap K} = z) P(X_{J \setminus K}=x-z)P(X_{K \setminus J}=y-z)$.

Tags: probability

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent random variables. Denote $X_J = \sum_{j \in J} X_j$ for $J \subset \{1, \ldots, n\}$. Then for $J, K \subset \{1,\ldots, n\}$,
$$
P(X_J=x, X_K=y)=\sum_{z} P(X_{J \cap K} = z) P(X_{J \setminus K}=x-z)P(X_{K \setminus J}=y-z). \quad (1)
$$

Let $x, y,z \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ and $J, K, L \subset \{1,\ldots, n\}$. Is there some identity for $P(X_J=x, X_K=y, X_L=z)$ which is similar to (1)? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle behind statement (1) is that the random variables $X_{J\cap K}$, $X_{J\smallsetminus  K}$, and $X_{K\smallsetminus J}$ are independent because the sets $J\cap K$, $J\setminus  K$, and $K\setminus J$ are disjoint.  Now as we have:  $$\begin{split}X_J&=X_{J\cap K}+X_{J\smallsetminus K}\\X_K&=X_{J\cap K}+X_{K\smallsetminus J}\end{split}$$

Then summing over all supported values of the common term gives us: $$\mathsf P(X_{\small J}{=}x,X_{\small K}{=}y)=\sum_z\mathsf P(X_{\small J\cap K}{=}z, X_{\small J\smallsetminus K}{=}x{-}z, X_{\small K\smallsetminus J}{=}y{-}z)$$

---

We may partition $J\cup K\cup L$ into a similar series of disjoint sets.$$X_J=X_{J\cap K\cap L}+X_{J\cap K\smallsetminus L}+X_{J\cap L\smallsetminus K}+X_{(J\smallsetminus K)\setminus L}\\X_K=X_{J\cap K\cap L}+X_{J\cap K\smallsetminus L}+X_{K\cap L\smallsetminus J}+X_{(K\smallsetminus J)\smallsetminus L}\\X_L=X_{J\cap K\cap L}+X_{J\cap L\smallsetminus K}+X_{K\cap L\smallsetminus J}+X_{(L\smallsetminus J)\smallsetminus K}$$

So...$$\mathsf P(X_{\small J}{=}x,X_{\small K}{=}y,X_{\small L}{=}z)=\sum_{t,u,v,w}\mathsf P({X_{\small J\cap K\cap L}{=}t},{X_{\small J\cap K\smallsetminus L}{=}u},{X_{\small J\cap L\smallsetminus K}{=}v},{X_{\small K\cap L\smallsetminus J}{=}w},{X_{\small J\smallsetminus K\smallsetminus L}{=}x{-}t{-}u{-}v},{X_{\small K\smallsetminus J\smallsetminus L}{=}y{-}t{-}u{-}w},{\small X_{L\smallsetminus J\smallsetminus K}{=}z{-}t{-}v{-}w})$$